# Showing div content with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp

I have a forgot password link. On clicking the link i want to display a div. Here is my demo code. There is something which i am missing. 
JSP Code:

```
<form action="login" method="post">
<label>Username :</label>
<input type="text" value="" name="email">
<label>Password :</label>
<input type="password" value="" name="password">
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Login" name="Login">
<div id="link"  class= "link">Forgot Password?</div>
</form>
<div id="forget-details"  class = "forget-details">
<h1>Forgot Your Password</h1>
<p>Enter your registered email address and we will send you a link to reset your password.</p>
<input type="text" value="" name="email" placeholder = "Enter your registered email"/>
```

CSS:

```
 form div.link{
color: #44869b;
cursor: pointer;
font-family: DIN,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
margin-top: 105px;
text-transform: inherit;
}
.forget-details {
 background-color: #333;
float: right;
margin: 7px 0;
padding: 11px;
width: 97%;
display:none;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".link").click(function(){
    $(".forget_details").show();
    });
 });
```

Comment: can you add a demo ??

Comment: Your class in HTML is `forget-details` but your selector in Javascript is `forget_details`. They need to be the same.

Comment: `$("#forget-details").show();` or `$(".forget-details").show();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `class="forget-details"` (hypen) but then select `$(".forget_details")` (underscore)

Answer (score 0):

Either Change your class name to `forget_details` or make this change

```
$(".forget-details").show();
```